# Retrieving data from the last recorded month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to retrieve the data for the last recorded month. So if we're in mid Jan and theres only data until mid Nov i'd like only Nov's data. Ive tried using `MAX` as well as `DATE_SUB` but that hasn't gotten me far.
My current code has the current_date which it shouldn't but it still doesn't work as intended as I get type issues presumably from my `datestamp` variable in the sub-query.

```
SELECT *
FROM trans_table
WHERE 
    PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', `Timestamp`) > DATE_TRUNC(DATE MAX(`Timestamp`), MONTH)
```

I've found a solution that is for me just too un-elegant for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM trans_table
WHERE 
    PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', `Timestamp`) > PARSE_DATE('%M/%d/%Y', (                                                
                                                                  SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', DATE (DATE_SUB(DATE (DATE_TRUNC(DATE (MAX(PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', `Timestamp`))), MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
FROM 
    trans_table)
```

This solution actually makes me laugh how bad it is.

Any help on the structure or syntax would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: parse out the max "Date" in a subquery/cte.  Then (Option 1) parse that out into year/month.  then filter your main table by it.  (Option 2) , you could just get the max date, then use a Truncate to to get the 1st day of that month, then dateadd to add 1 month.  then search for all dates inbetween.  (option 2 outlilned here) https://kontext.tech/column/code-snippets/708/bigquery-firstlast-day-of-month  Option 2 is better if you have indexes on your date/timestamp field. as it's able to leverage them.  (Basically your inelegant solution is what I'd do...)... So why is it you call it un-elegant?

Comment: Where you place the max function for option 2 as its not allowed in the WHERE clause hence why I put it in a subquery within the where clause?

Comment: That's he point of the CTE.  it lets you get the max date, and then you can cross join it to your base data since it's only 1 row/1 column, cross join won't present a cardinality issue.

Comment: It would help to have some sample data, and the type of `timestamp`.  Is your table partitioned on `Timestamp` ?

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

Something like:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT max(`Timestamp`) DateMax FROM trans_table)

SELECT A.*  CTE.DateMax
FROM trans_table A
CROSS JOIN CTE
WHERE `Timestamp` >= trunc(DateMax,month) and <= Last_day(datemax)
```

--Might need to truncate datemax so that it's just day/month/year and no time in order for the above where to work...